# A conjectured upper bound for the mean value of prime divisors inside prime gaps

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, conjectures, prime-gaps

In 1969 C.A. Grimm stated this [interesting conjecture](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2317188?seq=1): the prime gap $\,G_n=\{x\in N:p_n\lt x\lt p_{n+1}\}\,$ contains at least $\,\#G_n=(p_{n+1}-p_n)-1=g_n-1\,$ distinct prime divisors, that is if $\,V(n)=(p_n+1)(p_n+2)...(p_{n+1}-1)$
$$\omega\,[V(n)]\ge g_n-1$$
Let's define the following additive arithmetic function:
$$\sigma_p(n)=\sum_{k=1}^r p_k\;\;\;\;\;\;(\,n=\prod_{k=1}^r p_k^{a_k}\,)$$
Well, I have made some computations in order to conjecture a possible estimate for $\,\sigma_p(V(n))$. The following graph reports the values ($x10^6$) of $\,\sigma_p(V(n))-p_n\,$ till $\,n=10^5$:

[image]

A possible estimate should be
$$\sigma_p(V(n))=2n\,(\log n)^{3/2}+O(n\log n)$$
But under Cramér's conjecture $\,g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n=O((\log p_n)^2)$, therefore we can deduce the following upper bound for the mean value of prime divisors inside the gap $\,g_n$:
$$\frac {\sigma_p(V(n))} {\omega\,[V(n)]}\lt\frac {2n\sqrt {\log n}} {\log n+2\log {\log n}}\lt\frac {2n} {\sqrt {\log n}}$$
Notice that the max prime divisor inside the gap is less than
$$\frac {p_{n+1}} 2\sim\frac {n\log n+g_n} 2\sim\frac {n\log n+(\log n)^2} 2\sim\frac {\log n\,(n+\log n)} 2$$
**I ask your opinions and suggestions about the above arguments.**

Many thanks.

Comment: That's a bit nickpicking, but it would be better to denote the set by $G(n)$ so that $g_{n}:=p_{n+1}-p_{n}=\#G(n)+1$.

Comment: You are perfectly right. I have corrected the post. Thanks.